# How to Set Default Sharing Link to "People with Existing Access"

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

For SharePoint Online, can anyone identify a way to set the default tenant-wide link behavior so that it will default to "People With Existing Access"?

Currently, there are only 3 options present via the UI, and a 4th option "none" available via [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantmanagement.sharinglinktype.aspx) which sets the default link to the least restrictive option available.

[image: Current Tenant Settings]

The business need for this is that the other link options will break inheritance on a document or item and create a "shareable link". This could potentially result in unwanted sharing of sensitive information.

We are currently able to restrict this for the majority of the users by updating the access request settings (**Site Settings > User and Permissions > Site Permissions > Access Request Settings)** and disabling **Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders**. However, Site Owners can bypass this setting.

The desired outcome would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to activate ‘People with existing access’ by default when copying a link is to change:
SharePoint Administration > Sharing > File and folder links > Specific people.

https://ktnnsharepoint.wordpress.com/2019/08/01/share-copy-link-sharepoint-online/

Comment: But that link is having no effect

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at this time to do so. I would suggest voting on this idea.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/33706777-add-people-with-existing-access-to-the-default-l

Answer (score 0):

Since the answers are old and couple of new methods are available for this now. Currently, it is not possible to do this tenant wide using Admin center. But it is possible to set this at site level using PowerShell or via Admin Center for each site.

1. Using PowerShell loop through sites and set the flag

   ```
   $sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
   foreach ($site in $sites) {
      Set-SPOSite -Identity $site -DefaultLinkToExistingAccess $true
   }
   ```
2. Using Admin Center, Active sites page, select the site and click **Sharing**  on top ribbon. Now in the Sharing panel, you can change the default sharing link type

[image]